# What is the most elegant way to do "foreach x except y" in PHP?

Tags: php, optimization, loops, foreach

I want to do something like this:

```
foreach ($array as $key=>$value except when $key="id")
{
// whatever

}
```

... without having to put an "if" clause inside the body of the loop. It is not guaranteed that "id" will the be the first or last element in the array, and I don't really want to unset or slice the array, because that will be expensive, ugly, and not maintain the original data. I also definitely need to use both key and value inside the loop.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't think that the if-clause is such a problem:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if ($key == 'ignore_me') continue;
    if ($key == 'ignore_me_2') continue;
```

If you want a fancy solution, you can use [`array_diff_key`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php):

```
$loop_array = array_diff_key($actual_array, array('ignore_me' => NULL, 'ignore_me_2' => NULL));
foreach ($loop_array as $key => $value) {
    #...
```

Comment: which should work, but requires a stack more memory because it creates another copy of the array.

Comment: Yes it is, altered answer to reflect that.

Comment: Yes, I think putting those continues in in that sort of structure is the "neat" that I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Go with the if-clause inside the loop.
There is nothing inelegant about it, it is the easiest to read and understand, and it is the most efficient.

If you have many keys to skip you could build a second hash to test against (in the if-clause):

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
   if (array_key_exists($key,$skip_keys)) continue;
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll always end up to use an IF clause in the inner loop. Of all the options you already gave, that's the only one I would use for the speed and the memory consumption

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you can't do it without an `if` in the loop.

Like the keyword says, it's "for each", not "for most".

EDIT: like [soulmerge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/44562/soulmerge) says, you *could* do it with `array_diff_key()`, but if you're only missing out a single key it's more verbose and less memory efficient than just putting the `if` in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of compacting the `if` statement is:

```
// ignore 1,5,8,9
foreach($arr as $key){
  if(in_array($key, array(1,5,8,9)) continue;
  ...
}
```